# Duplicate warnings with include guard in Objective-C with C++ header

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, objective-c++

I have a file iforce2d_topdown_car.h in a demo project with an include guard like so:

```
#ifndef IFORCE2D_TOPDOWN_CAR_H
#define IFORCE2D_TOPDOWN_CAR_H

... source code ...

#endif
```

This is included in HelloWorldLayer.h, which is then included in two other files (this is all obj-c except for the iforce2d header). Everything compiles fine, but any errors I get are displayed 3 times. This annoys me, and I wonder if its symptomatic of a larger issue.

[image: Header funkiness in xcode]

Is this expected behavior? It seems to me that if a preprocessor var is defined, then it will stay defined and next time it is included it will not be compiled. It seems that is not the case here, but I do not know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TDCar(b2World *)` is an inline member function because it is defined inside its class definition. That means the compiler instantiates the function and emits the corresponding warnings in every translation unit that calls this function.

Let's imagine you have the following `A.h`:

```
class A {
public:
    int f(int i);
};
```

and `A.cpp`

```
int A::f(int i) {
    int j = i;
    return i + 1;
}
```

The compiler will compile the function `A::f(int i)` once and export it so every call to that function will link to the exported symbol. Therefore, the warning for the unused variable `j` will be emitted once: when `A.cpp` is compiled.

But if you write the following `A.h`:

```
class A {
public:
    int f(int i) {
        int j = i;
        return i + 1;
    }
};
```

Then the compiler will copy the code from the function definition directly into the source code file that calls the function. If you use that function in 3 different files, the function is compiled thrice and the warning is emitted thrice.

As each file is compiled individually, the compiler cannot know the warning was already emitted for another file.

Xcode should be clever enough to recognize the three warnings as being the same and aggregate them so you only get one warning. Unfortunately, Xcode isn't that clever.

Comment: Hi Nicholas, thanks for your answer. You have clarified a bit what's going on, but I'm still confused as to how the include guard is not keeping the code from being compiled more than once. Shouldn't the #define be run only once, and then the next two times it should not be compiled?

Comment: The include guard only keep the code from being included more that once **in the same translation unit**. If several source files include the same header, they all need the get to get its contents.

Comment: Ah ha! thanks for that! It seems this is unusual because of the original coder's usage of code within the header. I'll try not to do that with my own code.